# How to dynamically authorize users in MVC inside Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, asp.net-authorization, role-base-authorization

I am using MVC 5 to build an application. In my web.config I have defined a custom section which I will use to display menu to user. It is something like:

```
<Menus>
    <Menu>
        <MainMenu Title="Home"></MainMenu>
        <SubMenus>
            <SubMenu Title="Page1" PageName="home/index" ADGroup="BusinessUsers">
            <SubMenu Title="Page2" PageName="home/index2" ADGroup="ITUsers">
        </SubMenus>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <MainMenu Title="About Us"></MainMenu>
        <SubMenus>
            <SubMenu Title="Another Page1" PageName="about/mypage1" ADGroup="BusinessUsers">
            <SubMenu Title="Some Other Page" PageName="about/mypage2" ADGroup="OtherUsers">
        </SubMenus>
    </Menu>
</Menus>
```

I am using Windows authentication and everyone will have access via AD groups. By default I have denied access to all users using authorization rule in web.config like below:

```
<authorization><deny users="*"/></authorization>
```

Is it possible to define authorization rules based on MENU above in `Application_Start` at runtime? Something like:

```
Global.Filters.AuthorizeUser("BusinessUsers", "home/index, about/mypage1");
Global.Filters.AuthorizeUser("ITUsers", "home/index2");
```

Comment: That's in your web.config? Where is your code that pulls this out of your web.config and puts it into your view? That's likely where you would have to do this.

Comment: That is what I am asking i.e. how to authorize users at runtime. What is the code that I need to write in `Application_Start` to authorize respective users based on AD groups that are defined in `<Menu>`

Comment: I'm asking something different. Forget about authorization for a moment. How are you reading this from your web.config and putting it in your view?

Comment: If you want to do fine-grained authorization at runtime, you will need to look into a framework that does that either claims-based AuthZ in .NET or even XACML or ALFA.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am using `ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig` to read menu and then I loop through all the records in it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here isn't a standard way of defining a menu, so there is no standard way of enforcing authorization on it. You will need to implement it yourself.

Somewhere in your code during a request, you will have to loop through each SubMenu and use `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\GroupName")` to test whether the user is in the appropriate group. I can't give you any further direction than that without seeing more of your code.

I'm sure you have your reasons for putting this in web.config, but what I have done in my own projects is define the menu in a partial view and check the roles right in the view:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\GroupName") {
<a href="/something">Some menu item</a>
}
```

If you're worried about being able to update the menu items without recompiling the whole project, then that's still fine since the cshtml files aren't compiled anyway - you can update it on the fly.

Comment: I can display menu just fine. It is just simple HTML menu with main item and submenu. My problem is when a user clicks on any submenu then he will receive access denied error. Now what I want is somehow give that user access to that page via authorization at runtime. Otherwise I know one way of doing it is to define `location` in web.config but then it means I will have to define it in two places; one menu and second this location. I want everything to be done from one place i.e. my custom menu in web.config

Comment: "It is just simple HTML menu" - how does it become that? Are you processing that at application load?